# How to list nodes from a custom mib file using snmpwalk?

Tags: snmp, net-snmp, mib, oid, snmpwalk

I'm trying to add a custom mib file that contains few nodes.

For an example I tried loading SNMP-COMMUNITY-MIB as it's a standard mib and thus shouldn't throw errors.

I copied the mib into the path

```
~/.snmp/mibs
```

and also updated snmpd.conf as:

```
mibdirs +$HOME/.snmp/mibs
mibs +SNMP-COMMUNITY-MIB
```

I tried to print the oid of one of the nodes "snmpCommunityName" using:

```
 snmptranslate -m +SNMP-COMMUNITY-MIB -IR -On snmpCommunityName
```

it worked fine and the oid was printed.

I then tried to list all using snmpwalk:

```
 snmpwalk -v2c -c public localhost
```

But the nodes from my mib and its oid's were not printed.

How can I have my oids listed on snmpwalk?

Comment: Adding MIB documents is just step 1. You have to add the corresponding managed objects to the agent (at `localhost:161`) so that they can be queried. There are several approaches, and one of them is https://net-snmp.sourceforge.io/wiki/index.php/Tut:Extending_snmpd_using_shell_scripts

Answer (score 1):

I accidentally noticed that when I run `snmpwalk` without an OID, I get only 593 variables from my device, and the device-specific variables are missing. But if I add `1` as the OID, I get 2527 variables, including the ones which are the most useful. So in your case try adding `1` at the end of the snmpwalk command:

```
snmpwalk -v2c -c public localhost 1
```

Edit: The above method worked on an APC PDU, and on a Supermicro BMC. The BMC was a bit confusing because it did not use the OID names from the MIB file, but all the information I need is there.